# How to hide the 'RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE...' output when fitting ARIMA/SARIMAX model?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima, sarimax

I am fitting an ARIMA/SARIMAX model for a large dataset. When running the code I get the following output on my screen -

```
RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE

           * * *

Machine precision = 2.220D-16
 N =            4     M =           10

At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds

At iterate    0    f=  5.69245D+00    |proj g|=  1.98922D-01

At iterate    5    f=  5.64524D+00    |proj g|=  3.32004D-03

At iterate   10    f=  5.64521D+00    |proj g|=  1.27724D-03

At iterate   15    f=  5.64389D+00    |proj g|=  2.03358D-02

At iterate   20    f=  5.60506D+00    |proj g|=  4.45951D-02

At iterate   25    f=  5.60207D+00    |proj g|=  5.31460D-04

           * * *

Tit   = total number of iterations
Tnf   = total number of function evaluations
...
    4     28     32      1     0     0   1.993D-06   5.602D+00
  F =   5.6020645399394908     

CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL            
 This problem is unconstrained.
```

Since my dataset is quite large and I fit the ARIMA/SARIMAX models iteratively, I get multiple outputs as above which take up quite the screen space.

How do I hide/remove this output?

I tried using `model.fit(iprint=-1)` and `model.fit(disp=-1)` but I get error when I use either. I guess I am using the latest version of `statsmodels` where `disc` and `iprint` are deprecated. Is there another way to do this without downgrading to an earlier version of the statsmodels library?

My imports are as follows -

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
```

Comment: The docs for the current development still show disp, and don't say anything about deprecation. https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.fit What's the deprecation message you get?

Comment: I was using `ARIMA.fit(disp=-1)` and hence got the error `TypeError: ARIMA.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'`. However when I used it with `SARIMAX.fit()` there was no error.